# Removal of negative numbers from an array in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

My objective is to remove all negative numbers from an array in Java.

I have written the below code. How do I improve the complexity of code or is there a good algorithm?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = { 1, -3, 4, -9, 3, 4, 70, -10, 0, 7 };
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(removeNegativeNumbers(array)));
}

public static int[] removeNegativeNumbers(int[] num) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int n : num) {
        if (n >= 0) {
            list.add(n);
        }
    }
    int[] result = new int[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = list.get(i).intValue();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> How do I improve the complexity of code or is there a good algorithm?

Here is a linear `O(n)` algorithm with constant space (neglecting the space we need for output array). When an element is non-negative, copy the element and advance both output array and input array seeker. And when the element is negative, advance only the input array seeker(indx) and avoid copying to output array.

```
public static int[] removeNegativeNumbers(int[] num) {
    int[] output = new int[num.length];
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
       if(num[i] >= 0) {
           output[k++] = num[i];
       }
    }
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(output, 0, k);
}
```

#### Space Efficient Solution

You can make the algorithm *in-place* by transforming the input array to hold output like *insertion sort* way to avoid the space overhead of output array.

```
public static int removeNegativeNumbers(int[] num) {
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
       if(num[i] >= 0) {
           num[k++] = num[i];
       }
    }
    // Now input array is holding the output data
    // Return the length of output array
    return k;
}

// Usage: int newLen = removeNegativeNumbers(array);
```

This is called **two pointers technique**, very simple yet useful to solve many classical puzzles like Array de-duplication, merging two sorted arrays, intersection of two sorted arrays etc.

Comment: The space complexity is O(n), you can't call it constant.

Comment: @AnandTyagi Yes, I was returning by making a copy of input array.. thanks for pointing out. Now please check the update.

Comment: Note that the *second* code example is the one that is "in-place" - the first solution uses an auxiliary array.

Comment: +1 for several reasons. First, two implementations: a straightforward implementation and a more efficient, "trickier" one. Second, the array size is specified in advance (same as input array size). The code in the *question* uses an `ArrayList` which is dynamically re-sized as necessary, and the API hides the fact that the data structure can be expanded *well beyond* the needs of this algorithm and therefore hides a potentially-significant inefficiency.

Answer (score 53):

What about Java 8 streams?

```
Arrays.stream(num).filter(s -> s >= 0).toArray();
```

Comment: Best solution but 0 is not a negative number

Comment: This does certainly "improve the complexity of code", as the OP requested.

Comment: 97% of the time this is what you should use

Comment: +1 for short Java syntax. But this answer doesn't indicate anything about algorithm as OP requested. This just shows how powerful APIs Java has to be one-liners.

Comment: This will work for `int[]`, `long[]`, `double[]` and any `Object[]`, but not `byte[]`, `short[]`, `char[]`, or `float[]`, as there is no `Arrays.stream` method for those types.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think we can get better in terms of efficiency than @kaidul-islam answer (and @user6904265 in terms of conciseness).

I'm just adding a solution that should have some value in a very specific scenario, where negatives rarely appear and array is very large.

Basic idea is to defer the actual copy until a negative value is found and then copy with System.arraycopy. In case no negative is found, the source array would be returned.

```
import java.util.*;

public class NotNegativeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         int[] array = { 1, -3, 4, -9, 3, 4, 70, -10, 0, 7 }; 
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(removeNegativeNumbers(array))); 
    } 

    public static int[] removeNegativeNumbers(int[] num) {
         int[] output = new int[num.length];
         int k = 0;
         int i = 0; 
         int last=-1;
         int howmany=0;

         while(i < num.length) {
             if(num[i] < 0) {
                howmany=i-last-1;
                switch(howmany) {
                    case 0: break;
                    case 1: 
                            output[k]=num[last+1];
                            k++;
                            break;
                    default:        
                            System.arraycopy(num, last+1,  output, k, howmany);
                            k+=howmany;
                }
                last=i;
             } 
             i++;
         } 
         if (last>=0) {
              if(last!=i-1) {
                howmany=i-last-1;  
                System.arraycopy(num, last+1,  output, k, howmany);
                k+=howmany;
            }
        } else {
            return num;
        }

         return Arrays.copyOfRange(output, 0, k);
     }

}
```

I've found the time to write a JMH microbenchmark.

I've used used these configurations:

```
Options opts = new OptionsBuilder()
  .include(MyBenchmark.class.getSimpleName())
  .mode(Mode.AverageTime)
  .warmupIterations(1)
  .warmupTime(TimeValue.seconds(5))
  .measurementIterations(10)
  .measurementTime(TimeValue.seconds(5))
  .jvmArgs("-server")
  .forks(1)
  .build();
new Runner(opts).run();
```

(disclaimer: my first JMH test, so if someone has some suggestions, I'll be glad to change it and update the results)

And here are the results:

```
# Run complete. Total time: 00:02:54

Benchmark                             Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
MyBenchmark.testMethodUser6904265     avgt   10  0,201 ± 0,040   s/op
MyBenchmark.testMethodInsac           avgt   10  0,093 ± 0,022   s/op
MyBenchmark.testMethodKaidul          avgt   10  0,124 ± 0,029   s/op
```

Now, before cheering me, please take a look to how biased the test was:

```
 int[] array = new int[10000000];
 array[0]=-5;
 array[10000]=-3;
 array[40000]=-3;
 array[8000000]=-3;

 int[] answer=NotNegativeTest.removeNegativeNumbers(array);
```

So here the thing to notice it is not that my method won (the test was written for my method to win :-) but how close the generic kaidul-islam method was to mine even in this extreme scenario.

UPDATED: here is the link to the [jmh benchmark I wrote](http://pastebin.com/LhVq4Q1a) so you can verify more realistic scenario (if someone finds issues with how I setup the test, please let me know). There is a depenendency on Trove for a test I've done on another answer.

Comment: +1 for showing performance measures of three methods against your benchmark. Yes, for this type of scenario, your method will win definitely. And this can be done if we know the scenario beforehand. However, we can still make your method *in-place* if space is a concern.

Answer (score 7):

This will do it in-place with a single iteration:

Hold 2 indexes: `src` and `dst` on the original array. both are initialized to 0.

when a number is positive, copy it from `num[src]` to `num[dst]` and advance both indexes

when a number is negative, just advance `src`.

return the original array with `dst` as its new size.

```
public static int removeNegativeNumbers(int[] num) {
  int dst=0;
  for (int src=0 ; src<num.length ; ++src)
    if (num[src]>=0)
      num[dst++] = num[src];
  return dst;
}
```

Comment: This is certainly the fastest way.

Comment: It is also destructive, which may or may not be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the below code (Java 8)

```
int test[] = new int[] { 15, -40, -35, 45, -15 };
    // here we can take the test array in to stream and filter with condition (>=0).
    int[] positives = Arrays.stream(test).filter(x -> x >= 0).toArray();

    System.out.println("Here is the positive array elements");

    for (int i : positives) {
        System.out.print(i + "\t");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you will necessarily need to look at each individual element to determine if it is less than 0, the runtime must be at least O(n). Since the space needed to store the input is O(n), the space is at least O(n). Your solution runs in O(n) time with O(n) complexity, therefore **no solution can have better space or runtime complexity than your solution**

We can, however, get better results if we assume the array is sorted. Then, we do a binary search for 0. If we have a way to return the sub-array with constant time (e.g. pointer magic in C, or by simply returning the start index to be read), then the algorithm would have O(log n) time.

Comment: If you only consider the abstract time complexity then you neglect to count the overheads of the `Integer` boxing, compiler-generated typecasting, and dynamic reallocation associated with the `ArrayList<Integer>` in the question. It's still amortized O(n), but in practice it's not as fast as it could be.

Comment: @Boann, yes, that's true. There are several ways to deal with the ArrayList and boxing if you don't want amortized O (n) without increasing complexity. Those are covered by the other answers. I mostly wanted to address what other answers did not: OP's algorithm's complexity cannot be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Use iterator

```
  Iterator<Integer> itr = objArray.iterator();
     while(itr.hasNext()) {
     Integer next = itr.next();
     if(next < 0) {
        itr.remove();
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] removeNegativeNumbers(int[] num) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int n : num) {
        if (n >= 0) {
            list.add(n);
        }
    }
    return list.toArray(new int[list.size()]);
}
```

Comment: How is this any different from the code in the question?

Comment: @cricket_007 by using list.toArray, on an Arraylist,  he's optimizing the step from the list to the final array.   Behind the scenes list.toArray (remember,  list is an ArrayList) is using System.arrayCopy.

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if it included the explanation from @Insacs comment.

Comment: Won't compile. You can't call `toArray()` on a `List<Integer>` to get an `int[]`, only an `Integer[]`, which is horrid. The only way to get an `int[]` out of a list is to create and fill it manually, as the code in the question does.

Comment: @Boann you're right, and I didn't notice before :-(.. however, the answer is still salvegeable if the poster substitutes List<Integer> with some utility List of primitive ints (e.g. Trove TIntArrayList)